# Prove that area of $n$-gon approaches $\pi$ as $n$ approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits, circles

(A) Find and prove a formula for the area of the unit $n$-gon. An $n$-gon has $n$ evenly spaced points on the unit circle.
EDIT: Solution to part (a):
The area of a triangle is $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin{C}$, and if we let $a,b$ be radii and $C$ be the angle $\frac{360^\circ}{n}$, we get:
Area of one triangle = $\frac{1}{2}\times 1\times 1\times\sin{\frac{360^\circ}{n}}=\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{360^\circ}{n}}$

Because we have $n$ triangles, the area of the unit $n$-gon is $n\times\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin{\frac{360^\circ}{n}}\right)=\boxed{\frac{n}{2}\sin{\frac{360^\circ}{n}}}$

(B) Prove that has $n$ goes to $\infty$, the area approaches the area of the unit circle which is $\pi$.

For part (B), you may use calculus if necessary.

Comment: If $f(n)$ is the area of a unit $n$-gon, can you compute $f(3)$? What about $f(4)$?

Comment: Start by splitting the $n$-gon into triangles based at the $n$ edges and sharing a vertex at the center.  Note that your description produces a *regular* $n$-gon, so that each of these triangles are congrent (and therefore equal in area).

Comment: So something like $\text{Area of 1 triangle}=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin{C}=\frac{1}{2}\times 1\times 1\times\sin{\frac{360}{n}}$?  Anyway, I fail to see how to prove that this approaches $\pi$.

Comment: In your own words, the area of 1 triangle is $\frac{1}{2}\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$. But since we have $n$ triangles, then the area is $\frac{n}{2}\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Now take a limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Terminology: An $n$-gon means any $2$-dimensional polygon with $n$ sides. An $n$-gon whose vertices are evenly distributed upon a circle is called a regular $n$-gon, or a regular $n$-sided polygon.

Comment: In order to prove it you must have a definition of the area of the circle. What def'n do you have for this area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer for part A is correct, but how you got it is incorrect.  You don't need Calculus for part B, just an understanding of limits.  Indeed, this is the example I like to use, except using the perimeter approaching the circumference to show

$$ \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta} = 1 $$

Where $\theta$ is measured in radians.  You are using degrees, so I will stick with that.

Using the center of the circle as common vertex, your polygon can be partitioned into $n$ triangles.  Each is an isosceles triangle with the two equal sides having a length of one.  For a sample triangle, draw a line from the common vertex to halfway on the edge, call the length of this line $h$.  Let the length of the base be $b$.  The $h$ line is perpendicular to the $b$ line so the area of the triangle is $ \frac{1}{2} b h $.  The angle between the $h$ line and the long side is $ 180 / n $.  Thus the length of $b$ is $ 2 \sin(180/n) $.  Similarly, the length of $h$ is $ \cos(180/n) $.  Thus the area of the triangle:

$$ A = \frac{1}{2} b h = \frac{1}{2} 2 \sin(180/n) \cos(180/n) = \frac{1}{2} \sin(360/n) $$

The last step comes from the double angle formula for sines.

The perimeter, call it $p$, is the sum of all the bases of the isosceles triangles.

$$ p = n b $$

The total area for all the triangles is:

$$ A_{total} = n \frac{1}{2} b h $$

Now come the limits.  The first is easy to see.

$$ lim_{ n \to \infty } h = 1 $$

The second is just as intuitive.  The length of the perimeter of the polygon as the number of sides approaches infinity is the circumference of the circle.

$$ \lim_{ n \to \infty } p = 2 \pi $$

$$ \lim_{ n \to \infty } A_{total} = \lim_{ n \to \infty } n \frac{1}{2} b h = \lim_{ n \to \infty } \frac{1}{2} p h = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \pi \cdot 1 = \pi $$

Hope this helps.

Ced

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{\theta\to 0}{\sin\theta/\theta}=1$$ for $\theta$ *in radians.*